# How to get the values of input using PHP

Tags: php, html

Hey i'm having a problem where I cannot seem to get the value of an input using PHP, I have a form in HTML and another file named "handle.php" which i prints the value of username but when I submit It directs me to the file "handle.php" and does not print anything, just shows the script.

I tried doing the script inside the HTML but I got the same result, nothing happened so I thought maybe I need to make a function and then call it onclick but it didn't do anything eventually I made a separate file named "handle.php" and in the form I did "action="handle.php" which lead to the first problem.

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Hide/Show Password Login Form</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="login_form">
            <section class="login-wrapper">

                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>

                <form id="login" method="post" action="handle.php">

                    <label for="username">User Name</label>
                    <input required name="login[username]" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" />

                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input class="password" required name="login[password]" type="password" />
                    <div class="hide-show">
                        <span>Show</span>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit">Sign In</button>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

handle.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['login[username]'];
?>
```

Comment: If it just shows the script, it means the code is not parsed as PHP. Do you have PHP installed?

Comment: No do you need to Install it? I thought its automatically installed on every windows

Comment: `$_POST['login']` is an array - you want `$_POST['login']['username']` - this is why just having password/username as the input name tends to be preffered

Comment: @yarinCohen yes, you need something like Xampp (https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) to have PHP running locally

Comment: now u have multiple answers, check them and accept the best answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using this `name="login[password]"` you can get the values in PHP as:

```
print($_POST['login']['password']);
```

One more solution, store input array in a variable like:

```
$post = $_POST['login'];
```

then, use like:

```
echo $post['password']
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['login'];` will return a php array with all keys you used in your form. So you get the `username` key of this array like this:

```
echo $_POST['login']['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

first try to print only **$_POST** then you see what is you get in request.
always help to you for following this method. debug step by step then get the data into array.

```
<?php 
$request=$_POST['login'];
echo $request["username"];
echo $request["password"];

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace textbox name as username in html code and Change php code as  echo $_POST['username'];  in handle.php

In Html code,

```
<input required name="username" type="text" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" />
```

In php code( handle.php),

```
echo $_POST['username'];
```